# How to properly persist a Doctrine's query instance?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Into a web workflow I need to pass a query from request to another trought PHP sessions.

Unfortunatly I can't pass a Doctrine's query because it's contained a resource, which is not sierializable.

At the moment I transform my Doctrine's query object into a SQL string one, and I persist it into my session with parameters to bound. But with this method I can't add SQL conditions when I get back the query from the session (my query can have `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`, or other statment at the end...).

If I'd succeed in getting back a Doctrine's query object it solved my problem, when using query builder the order of statments is not important.

Do you know a way to bypass this problem?

Exemple of query I would like to persist:

```
$query = $this->app['db']->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('e.n AS Name'
        , 'SUM(nb) AS Nombre'
        , 'ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN data = 2 THEN nb END) * CAST(100 AS float) / SUM(nb), 2) AS [Data type 2]')
    ->from('myDb.dbo.tableA', 'i')
    ->leftJoin('i', 'myDb.dbo.tableB', 'e', 'e.id = i.id')
    ->where("ind = :ind")->setParameter('ind', $this->ind)
    ->andWhere("(DATEPART(wk, date) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE()))")
    ->andWhere("e.country= :country")->setParameter('country', 'UK')
    ->groupBy("e.n")
    ->orderBy("e.n");

if(!$app['isAdmin'])
    $query->andWhere("e.userPermission = :userPermission")->setParameter('userPermission', $app['user']);

$qb = $this->app['session']->set('query', $query);
```

I use Symfony's session component.

Comment: A dql is just a string, what is preventing you from saving it?

Comment: @didierc I tought that the object created with the Doctrine query builder was named *DQL*, I update my question to remove my error.

Comment: I am confused, there you seem to be doing regular *SQL*, but you chose to cut the query in pieces and pass each of them back to the Builder by method calls. Is that a simplified version of your code using constants? Why don't you use *DQL*?

Comment: @didierc I don't use Doctrine ORM but Doctrine DBAL. I've not seen DQL mention into the DBAL's documentation, so I use Doctrine's [QueryBuilder](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) in order to allow me to add `WHERE` clause without the need to take care of the SQL clause order.

Comment: OK, I guess the only way is to turn the method calls into a serializable representation, it means you need to encode each call into some sort of algebraic datatype. Thelse are not supported in php, but you can do away with constants.

Comment: Are you sure you really need to persist a query in the session?  Seems like storing the where parameters and then building the query would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments, you could transform the method call chain on `$query` into something that is serializable. Other languages have this language construct called *algebraic data type* which let you precisely encode a set of alternatives (ie. possible values) within a type (a simpler construct exists in C called `enum`). That doesn't exist in PHP but it may be emulated with constants.

```
// original code

$query = $this->app['db']->createQueryBuilder(); 
$query->select('e.n AS Name' , 'SUM(nb) AS Nombre' , 'ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN data = 2 THEN nb END) * CAST(100 AS float) / SUM(nb), 2) AS [Data type 2]')
      ->from('myDb.dbo.tableA', 'i')
      ->leftJoin('i', 'myDb.dbo.tableB', 'e', 'e.id = i.id')
      ->where("ind = :ind")
      ->setParameter('ind', $this->ind)
      ->andWhere("(DATEPART(wk, date) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE()))")
      ->andWhere("e.country= :country")
      ->setParameter('country', 'UK')
      ->groupBy("e.n")
      ->orderBy("e.n"); 
if(!$app['isAdmin'])
  $query->andWhere("e.userPermission = :userPermission")
        ->setParameter('userPermission', $app['user']);
$qb = $this->app['session']->set('query', $query);



// algebraic representation, which is serializable


$query = [
   "default" => [
      "select"       => ['e.n AS Name' , 'SUM(nb) AS Nombre' , 'ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN data = 2 THEN nb END) * CAST(100 AS float) / SUM(nb), 2) AS [Data type 2]'],
      "from"         => ['myDb.dbo.tableA', 'i'],
      "leftJoin"     => ['i', 'myDb.dbo.tableB', 'e', 'e.id = i.id'],
      "where"        => ["ind = :ind"],
      "andWhere"     => [
          ["(DATEPART(wk, date) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE()))"],
          ["e.country= :country"]
      ],
      "groupBy"      => ["e.n"],
      "orderBy"      => ["e.n"]
   ],
   "tuning"   => [
      "not_admin"    => [
          "andWhere"     => ["e.userPermission = :userPermission"],
      ]
   ]
];
```

Using `string` values for tags, and arrays for parameters, we actually end up with something fairly readable.

Now, to turn this back into the original call chain, we only need to use `call_user_function_array`.

```
// executing the above

function chaincall($query, $method, $params) {
    if (is_array($params[0]))
        foreach ($params as $call)
            call_user_func_array([$query,$method], $call);
    else
        call_user_func_array([$query,$method], $params);
}


$query = $this->app['db']->createQueryBuilder();
// baseline query
foreach ($query_data['default'] as $meth => $params) {
    chaincall($meth, $params);
}
// non admin user query tuning
if(!$app['isAdmin'] && isset($query_data['tuning']['not_admin']){
foreach ($query_data['not_admin'] as $meth => $params) {
    chaincall($meth, $params);
}
// other kind of query tuning?
// ...
// parameters
$query->setParameter('ind', $this->ind)
      ->setParameter('userPermission', $app['user']);
```

I have tried to follow the logic of your original code by specifying query "tuning"<sup>1</sup>  according to the application state in the serializable value, but you can easily extract or refactor that code as you see fit.

This code is quite simple and leverage PHP flexibility, but it isn't safe. I would recommend replacing method name string literals (eg "select", "andWhere") by real constants (that's the *enum* part), and use an array to check that the method is authorised, or wrap the query object with an object exporting only these methods.
Likewise, I would probably break down query fragments further into the smallest possible elements (atoms) according to DQL grammar, but this would complicate the execution part sensibly.

---

<sup>1: for lack of a better term.</sup>

Comment: Your idea is pretty good, furthermore I just see into Doctrine's API some helper to perform it: [`$queryBuilder->getParts();` to serialization and `$queryBuilder->add();` to deserialization](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.3/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Query.QueryBuilder.html)

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about these, but you may indeed use them.